# heroku deployment error [Item could not be created: Unauthorized]

Tags: heroku, namecheap

I recently set up a web app on heroku and got the domain from namecheap.  Everything is working except that now when I try to deploy a change from my github repo, I get the following error in a red flag in the upper right corner.

Item could not be created:
Unauthorized

Does anyone know why this started happening after linking it to a domain?

Comment: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413

Comment: i have the same problem, so i'm here with you, i disconnected my github because it wasn't pushing and now it wont reconnect.

Comment: I had to use the heroku cli as the article suggested and was able to get the app deployed.